# Stop flickering in jquery-ui dropdown

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-transitions, flicker

I have a jquery-ui dropdown on my page, and generally links make use of smooth transitions, Now I find that in FF the dropdown actually flickers when I hover over the different options.

See http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/495/

```
a {
text-decoration: underline;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
color: #50444a;
border-bottom-color: #ab939f;
}
```

I'm not sure what css to add to prevent the transition effects to effect the jquery-ui suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #50444a;
    border-bottom-color: #ab939f;
}
```

Removed transition and it worked perfect!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBduF/496/)

Comment: Great it works in the example, only not on my site :( I'm afraid i have some more nested css layers which obstruct it...

Comment: you can use chrome developer tools to see what all styles are applicable on that object/element